# Regex negative lookbehind assistance

Tags: regex, pcre

I could use a hand with what is probably a simple regex. I need to match on lines that contain the string `birth_dt_tm` that are not preceded by `datetimezoneformat(`. I tried using a negative lookbehind but both lines in my sample text are matching.

Sample lines:

```
    dob = datetimezoneformat(p.birth_dt_tm, p.birth_tz, "MM/DD/YYYY")
    dob2 = format(p.birth_dt_tm, "MM/DD/YYYY;;d")
```

what I tried:

```
^.*(?<!datetimezoneformat\().*birth_dt_tm
```

Using PCRE, this matches both lines from the start of the line through `birth_dt_tm`.  I just want it to match the second line.

See here for sample - https://regex101.com/r/lv4nGK/1

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehind in PCRE doesn't support dynamic length matches. You can use PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to skip and fail a match that you don't want in your results using **alternation** and on RHS use what you want to match:

```
\bdatetimezoneformat\([^)]*\bbirth_dt_tm\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\bbirth_dt_tm\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hj4cBB/2)

Comment: Awesome thanks.  That does seem to return what I wanted.  What about the following though?  It also appears to work.
(?<!datetimezoneformat\()(\w\.birth_dt_tm)

Comment: that won't work if `birth_dt_tm` is 2nd parameter, for example this string: `dob = datetimezoneformat(p.birth_tz, p.birth_dt_tm, "MM/DD/YYYY")`. Also this regex matches `p.birth_dt_tm` instead of `p.birth_dt_tm`

Comment: it wouldn't ever be the second parameter to that function.  Actually, I think this might work well enough:
`\bformat\b.*\bbirth_dt_tm\b`

Comment: it won't even work for `dob = datetimezoneformat( pb.birth_dt_tm, p.birth_tz, "MM/DD/YYYY" )`

Comment: As you can negative lookahead approach is faulty and error prone.